# PowerBI - Date Slicer Breaks 'ALL' Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I have 2 measures showing the rate for crew and site. The crew measure excludes when an operator is selected and the site measure excludes when both crew and operator are selected. These measures should still be effected by all other slicers (I have a slicer for machine, date and material type as well as operator and crew).

The measures are as follows:

Crewrate=
CALCULATE([rate]
,ALL(Table1[Operator]))

Siterate = CALCULATE([rate]
,ALL(Table1[Crew],Table1[Operator])
)

They work fine when I have no date selected:

[image: Pic of measures working w no selected date]

But my problem is that as soon as I select a timeframe, the measures break and suddenly all the filters I wanted to exclude are applied again:

[image: Pic of broken measures w date selected]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Tried remove filters, keepfilters and using different date source

Comment: Have you tried ALLSELECTED() instead of ALL()?

Comment: Hi Marcos, AllSELECTED doesn't work either - same result as ALL

Answer (score 0):

To anyone experiencing the same issue as me,
I found that grouping my dates and using the grouped dates in the slicer instead fixed the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).